# What's the best way to do a bulk namespace rename on a large c# application?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, refactoring

First, a little background.

Currently namespaces and assemblies in our codebase (~60 assemblies, thousands of classes) looks like

```
WidgetCompany.Department.Something
```

We have now been spun off such that we are selling the software that drives a WidgetCompany, so we 'd like to rename the namespaces & assemblies

```
NewCompany.Something
```

Under normal circumstances I'd probably just stick with the old namespace, but the problem is our customers don't want to see the name of one of their competitors anywhere in the application.  In the off chance that they see a stack trace, assembly properties etc, it shouldn't show up.  It's not meant to hide our associates or do anything sinister, we just need to make sure that people know we are a separate entity, separate management, and they don't need to worry about data being shared etc.

Now the question.  What is the best way to perform this type of all encompassing rename?
The following would need to change:

- Namespace for (almost) every class in
  the application
- Every `using` statement in the application which references the old names
- Folder structure for each project
- References between projects which rely on changed folder structure
- .Sln files which reference the changed folder structure
- Any references to
  those classes which are fully
  qualified (should be few and far
  between)
- Any references to those
  classes in xml config files (config
  sections etc)
- AssemblyInfo.cs files for every assembly
- AssemblyName in every .csproj file

Am I stuck with the find-replace-pray strategy or is there something better?

Comment: Check in, find-replace, build.  Or ReSharper, probably.

Comment: Is the new NameSpace in a new .dll or same dll with namespace changed and recompiled

Comment: Does resharper have a refactor=>change namespace?  It's been a while since I've used it, but I didn't think it did.

Comment: @Shekhar_Pro: I guess that defines how you define a new dll.  It will be a differently named dll containing differently namespaced classes, but I was thinking I'd leave the .csproj files in place and just rename things.  I'm open to creating new projects if there's an easy way.

Comment: Resharper's refactor does include a namespace rename option.  http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/renaming.html

Comment: as @Will suggested the strategy would be to find and replace and then remove the reference to old dll and build the solution.. any errors will point you to where you missed renaming.. Also i think Resharper will be a good alternative

Comment: Interesting, it looks like resharper has a new refactoring called "Adjust Namespaces", that has promise!

Comment: I also revised the question to include the folder structure related items (folders themselves, sln files, .csproj files, references etc)

Comment: Don't forget to rename the Assembly Name and Default Namespace in each project's Properties. If you don't, all new classes, controllers, etc will have the old namespace, and Resharper will nag you endlessly to adjust the namespaces.

Comment: @RobertCorvus: Those are stored in the .csproj (default namespace) and AssemblyInfo.cs (assembly name) as listed above.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Right click on your current namespace and select Refactor -> Rename and change the name in the pop up that comes up after a while. Enter your new name and click ok.

If you have multiple depths to your namespace, then Visual Studio won't let you type a dot. However, if you copy and paste a dot, despite a warning, it will do the business.

To completely change to the new name, you will likely need to make additional changes manually. You can find where by performing a project search (ctrl+shift+f) for other references to the name in the Project, Solution, or other supporting files from a separate text editor like VS Code. Finally, folders may need to be changed manually as well.

Comment: Last time I checked that doesn't work for multiple levels of a namespace such as level1.level2.level3.  If the namespace is a single level, without a dot, then it works fine.  This was VS 2008 SP1.

Comment: I guess you could do it one symbol at a time. (I havent tried that though.)

Comment: +1 because that helps with the strongly typed stuff, but doesn't help with the assembly names, csproj files, xml files etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem to help if you want to add some additional namespace at the root

Comment: Downvoted as incorrect. Doesn't answer the original question, since you can't move or remove namespace components this way.

Comment: Simple namespace change works, but obvious places are missed like cshtml files. I had to do a find and replace all at the end. (VS2013)

Comment: Re multi level changes (with dots). This bug still exists (VS 2015) in that it won't let you *type* a dot. However, if you copy and *paste* a dot, despite a warning, it will do the business.

Comment: I should say that the above comment is useful for *adding* levels; it doesn't help to take them away or rename multiple levels in one go.

Comment: @BobSammers This should be included in the answer! Copying and pasting did it!

Comment: @BobSammers I added your response to the answer. I think it would help a lot of people since most probably don't look through comments.

Comment: I am wondering why dot is not allowed, that is weird that we should copy a dot instead of typing it.

Answer (score 10):

ReSharper. Get version 5.1 from JetBrains for free for 30 days (more than enough time to do your renaming). Put the cursor on the namespace you want to change and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> twice (ReSharper Rename). It'll work with a namespace any number of levels deep, and converts any usage of that namespace to the new one. However, you will have to change every unique namespace in your solution (unless you just go with Find/Replace)

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition supports this as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/move-type-to-namespace?view=vs-2019). It works for any hierarchy (with dots, root namespace changes etc) and correctly updates all dependencies.

1. Place your cursor in the **class name**
2. Press **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu
3. Select **Move to namespace** [image: Move to namespace refactoring]
4. In the dialog box that opens, select the target namespace you'd like to move the type to [image: Select a namespace dialog box]

Answer (score 7):

**For Visual Studio 2022 this has *finally* been solved:**

- Right-click on the project or solution (not the directory or file)
- Select "Sync Namespaces"

The namespaces in your entire project should now reflect the folder structure.

Answer (score 5):

If you have ReSharper:

1. Right click project, **Properties**. Change Default namespace to desired
   namespace.
2. Right click project, **Refactor** -> **Adjust Namespace** to update all
   the namespaces to use the default namespace

Then just let it do its magic.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would try `Refactor->Rename` option. But as mentioned in comment for another answers it doesn't work that good (Or I haven't found how to make it working). So I prefer using following scenario, especially if you want to add some addiotional namespace.

1) Rename your root namespace (`WidgetCompany`) to something like `NAMESPACE_TO_BE_REPLACED` using `Refactor-Rename`
2) Replace `NAMESPACE_TO_BE_REPLACED` with your final namespace (`NewCompany.WidgetSoftware`) using find-n-replace dialog

And do not forget to rename projects, default namespaces, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Open a random class in [WidgetCompany.Department.Something]
- Edit->Find and Replace->Replace in Files
- Type "WidgetCompany.Department.Something" in *FindWhat* area
- Type "NewCompany.Something" in *Replace with* area
- Select Current Project in *Look in* area.
- Replace All

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution if you've already partially renamed:

- Open find and replace (shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>)
- Make sure regex is selected (icon like `.*`)
- Paste the full name of your current namespace, for example `YourSolution.YourProject`
- Paste this regex `YourSolution.Your[partiallyRenamedNamespaceCharacters].*`
- Make sure `Entire Solution` is selected not `Current Document`
- Run