# Any ways we can refactor/rename folder in Visual Studio with its namespace also got renamed automatically?

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-2010

In eclipse, when we refactor/rename the folder name, the namespace will got rename automatically. So we don't need to go to each single file to rename the namespace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809197/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-bulk-namespace-rename-on-a-large-c-sharp-application

Comment: hi Gil, it is not a duplication, I am asking if there is any way the refactoring can be like the way eclipse does.

Comment: do you work with resharper?

Comment: yes. if u happen to work in eclipse, when u rename any folder in eclipse, it will auto rename all the namespaces. resharper tools is cool but it dont have such function afaik.

Answer (score 0):

When using resharper you may adjust the namespaced automatically based on the folder names ([resharper documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html)).
The easiest flow would be:
1. Right click the folder name and click rename (change the folder name)
2. Right click the folder name -> hoover over "refactor" -> click "Adjust namespaces..." ([image: image: folder menu right click])
3. "Adjust Namespaces" windows appear and you may choose files where you want to fix namespaces
([image: image: Adjust Namespaces resharper window])