# I inadvertently used the same name for namespace as well as the class name, and need to rename all instances of one of them

Tags: c#, .net, azure-service-fabric

I inadvertently used the same name for namespace as well as the class name, and need to rename all instances of one of them... is it easier to getaway with just renaming the class?

I went through a few existing questions on the topic:

1. [Should a class have the same name as the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803744/should-a-class-have-the-same-name-as-the-namespace)
2. [What's the best way to do a bulk namespace rename on a large c# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809197/whats-the-best-way-to-do-a-bulk-namespace-rename-on-a-large-c-sharp-application/4809300)

What is certain, is that the names of Namespaces and Classes definitely need to be unlike. And it seems like even though you can refactor a Namespace, it needs to manually be changed in several more files.

Thus, should I simply rename the class name, which is only to be renamed in four places: class name definition itself, the constructor, and two places in the Program.cs file (This is an Azure Service Fabric application).

Am I missing any place the class name needs to be changed?

Comment: It is usually easier to rename the class, as in easier to coax the IDE into doing the right thing. Whether it's **the right thing** to do is something you will have to decide yourself. If you use rename refactoring in the IDE it should rename the class, the constructor, usages, and filename. If you have referred to the class name in a string (which you shouldn't, use `nameof(type)` instead), you might have to manually fix those afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

If you choose to use Visual Studio, you can easily change file names. Here's how:

1. Go to `Source Explorer`.
2. Right click on the file you want to rename > Click on `Rename`.

   [image]
3. A dialog box appears > click on `Yes`.

   [image]

*This will rename all the references of the file in your solution.*